# Redirecting parked domain pages to all co-existing pages in new domain

Tags: javascript, html, .htaccess, google-analytics

I have two domains running with all the same pages, one of them is parked but all pages on both domains are the exact same.

The problem I need resolved is that all pages indexed by google are from the parked domain and needs to be redirected to the new domains pages

e.g www.parked.com/notparked.html to www.live.com/notparked.html

Any help with how to go about getting this right? Is it even possible?

Comment: `javascript` and `html` probably wont help

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean the same path?

Both two have the same location.pathname in JavaScript,

so you can easily use http://your.new.host concat window.location.pathname get the new url.

for example:

```
$('a').click(function(event){
   event.preventDefault();
   window.location.href = "http://your.new.host" + window.location.pathname;
})
```